# Cannot update quantity, keep showing quantity value '1'

Tags: php, mysqli

I could not update my item quantity in my shopping cart and database table as well. Is there any error?I'm not using session to record the items that added into cart. Sorry I'm not good in coding. Doing this for my final year project. Thanks!

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table width="100%"  cellpadding="6" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
        <tr height="32">
            <th width="10%">QTY</th>
            <th width="37%">ITEM(S)</th>
            <th width="18%">PRICE</th>
            <th width="19%">TOTAL</th>
            <th width="16%">REMOVE</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php

    $total = 0; //set initial total value

    global $con;
    $ip = getIp();

    $sel_price = "select * from cart where ip_add = '$ip'";
    $run_price = mysqli_query($con, $sel_price);

    while($p_price = mysqli_fetch_array($run_price)){

        $qty = $p_price['qty'];
        $cart_id = $p_price['cart_id'];
        $pac_id = $p_price['p_id'];
        $pac_price = "select * from package where package_id = '$pac_id'";
        $run_pac_price = mysqli_query($con, $pac_price);

        while($pp_price = mysqli_fetch_array($run_pac_price)){
        //set variables to use in content below
        $package_title = $pp_price['package_title'];
        $package_image = $pp_price['package_image'];
        $package_price = array($pp_price['package_price']);
        $single_price = $pp_price['package_price'];


        $subtotal = ($single_price * $qty); //calculate Price x Qty
        $total = ($total + $subtotal); //add subtotal to total var





?>
        <tr class="'.$bg_color.'">
            <td><input type="text" size="2" maxlength="2" name="qty" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['qty'];?>" />
            </td>
            //update quantity part
            <?php

    if(isset($_POST['update_cart'])){

        $qty = $_POST['qty'];
        $update_qty = "update cart set qty='$qty' where cart_id='$cart_id'";
        $run_qty = mysqli_query($con, $update_qty);

        $_SESSION['qty']=$qty;

        $subtotal = ($single_price * $_SESSION['qty']);

    }

    ?>

            <td><br><?php echo $package_title; ?><br>
    <img src="admin_area/product_images/<?php echo $package_image; ?>" width="80" height="80"/><br></td>
            <td><?php echo "RM".$single_price; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo "RM".$subtotal; ?></td>
            <td><a href="removefromcart.php?delete_cart=<?php echo $cart_id ?>"><img src ="admin_area/img/icons/delete.png"/></a></td>

        </tr>

<?php }} ?>
<tr>
    <td colspan="5">
    <span style="float:right;text-align: right;">Amount Payable : <?php echo "RM" .sprintf("%01.2f", $total);?>     
    </span>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="5">
    <a href="checkout.php" class="button">Checkout</a>
    <a href="funeral_package.php" class="button">Add More Items</a>
    <button type="submit" name="update_cart">Update</button>
    </td>
</tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

</form>
```

Comment: Try adding or die(mysqli_error()); behind the execution of the query (so behind mysqli_query()) to see what error you're getting.

Comment: update cart set qty=qty+'$qty' where cart_id='$cart_id'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have use here  $PreV_qty as a variavle. that means you have to get previous qty and then update

```
if(isset($_POST['update_cart'])){ 


$PreV_qty = $_SESSION['qty'];
$qty = $PreV_qty+$_POST['qty'];
$update_qty = "update cart set qty='$qty' where cart_id='$cart_id'";
$run_qty = mysqli_query($con, $update_qty);
$_SESSION['qty']=$qty;

$subtotal = ($single_price * $_SESSION['qty']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try moving below section to top of the script

```
if(isset($_POST['update_cart'])){

    $qty = $_POST['qty'];
    $update_qty = "update cart set qty='$qty' where cart_id='$cart_id'";
    $run_qty = mysqli_query($con, $update_qty);

    $_SESSION['qty']=$qty;

    $subtotal = ($single_price * $_SESSION['qty']);

}
```

or above `<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">`